# Number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ of positive integers such that $x+y=90$ and their GCD is $6$

Tags: combinatorics

> The number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ of positive integers such that $x+y=90$ and their greatest common divisor is $6$ equals $8$.

But I did this way: As $x$ and $y$ both are divisible by $6$, so let $x=6m$ and $y=6n$, so $m+n=15.$  So, $\binom{15-1}{2-1}=14.$
 Where am I wrong?

Comment: The numbers $m$ and $n$ must be relatively prime. So $m=3,5,6,\dots$ are no good.

Comment: So, I should check all those $14$ pairs, Right?@AndréNicolas

Comment: The $14$ pairs you initially come up with ignore symmetry cases. So you really have $7$ potential pairs. It really should be quick to start checking. If $m = 1$, then what must be $n$? If $m = 2$? You get the idea.

Comment: Since our numbers are small, that is probably optimal strategy. For a number quite a bit bigger than $15$, say $B$, the candidates $m$ would be the numbers from $1$ to $B-1$ that are relatively prime to $B$. There are $\varphi(B)$ such numbers (Euler $\varphi$-function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are halfway there. Since 6 is exactly the GCD, those m and n you mention must be relative primes. There are 7 ordered pairs that add up to 15 ( (1,14),(2,13)...(7,8)), but 3 of those ((3,12),(5,10),(6,9)) are not relative primes. So there are 4 solutions.

(6,84), (12,78), (24,66), (42,48)

Comment: It is *ordered pairs*, so we need to double.

Comment: OK, Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh, I thought "ordered" means that they are sorted by order.

Comment: @BalazsRau: "Ordered pair" has only one standard meaning. If the set of all pairs $(x,y)$ with $x\lt y$ had been intended, that would have been made clear.